# What fact(s) prove JIT compiler is built in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jit

Eclipse is able to recognize the compiling error of code before running, because of the JIT compiler?

Comment: ...no?  Eclipse runs a perfectly normal bytecode compiler (if one optimized for incremental compilation), not a JIT.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Then how it is possible to detect any syntax errors without compiling? I remember C++ compiler gives error warning after compiling.

Comment: What are you talking about? JITting has nothing to do with compiler errors.

Comment: @JiajuShen: Who said it wasn't compiling?  It's just doing a normal bytecode compilation, not JIT-compiling, which by definition only happens while the program is actually being run.

Comment: @LouisWasserman So it compiles automatically meanwhile with the user input word by word?

Comment: @JiajuShen: It doesn't need to do full compilation for that - just part of it. Parsing and some semantic analysis, updating its internal data structures etc. It doesn't need to emit byte code on the fly. It's really important that you understand the difference between a Java compiler and a JIT compiler though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None, because there isn't one. The JDT project includes a Java compiler, but a [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) would only ever be part of a Java Runtime. As download.eclipse.org points out:

> You will need a Java runtime environment (JRE) to use Eclipse (Java SE
>   7 or greater is recommended).

Ergo, it doesn't contain one itself.